# Mustache.js data from JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, mustache

I am currently working on jQuery Mobile site which will use data from JSON source.
To generate HTML I am using Mustache.js - javascript template engine.

I have a problem with `AJAX -> JSON -> MUSTACHE` as the JSON data is not being rendered properly.

All works fine all long JSON data is in same file and I am not using AJAX at all. 
Please have a look a this **[demo](http://piotr.site44.com/index.html)**.

JSON:

```
[{
    "users": [{
        "userName": "Billy Bob",
            "userId": "2AE5F6D0-5A70-4EBF-BBAA-C0A11E74BFD8",
            "securityLevel": "Admin",
            "createdDate": "9/12/2012"
    }]
}]
```

TEMPLATE:

```
var template = "{{#users}}\
            <li class='userRow'>\
            <span class='userField'><a href='#' class='userLink' userId='{{userId}}'>{{userName}}</a></span>\
            <span class='userField'>{{securityLevel}}</span>\
            <span class='userField'>{{createdDate}}</span>\
            </li>\
            {{/users}}";
```

AJAX (AJAX call is OK, returns JSON with code 200.)

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'http://piotr.site44.com/json.js',
                type: 'post',
                data: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                                    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data); 
                    $(html).appendTo('#cnt');

                }

            });
```

**When I do `console.log(html)` it is actually showing empty string in console. Very odd. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Do you know how to debug? If yes, it's simple. Put a break-point at the beginning of the success handler. Then break on it. First, check if `data` is indeed the correct object. Next, step over the `var html =` statement, and check if Mustache returns the correct HTML string (and also check `template`). If no, [learn it](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints). `:P`

Comment: Is the ajax request returning properly formed json? I'd verify that in the response.

Comment: Also, I'd stay away from those multi-line strings. Keep your template in `<script>` blocks on your page, if you can.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - yes, I am using FireBug. All looks ok. But, the `html` returns as a empty string. Nothing returned from `Mustache.to_html`

Comment: @kinakuta - JSON was not valid, updated now. Still does not work. `Mustache.to_html`  return empty string.

Comment: @NewUser Can you post your JSON?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - can you give me an example of how to use template as a seperate script block?

Comment: @kinakuta - http://piotr.site44.com/json.js

Comment: @NewUser The outer `[]` wrapper is the problem. Your JSON structure should be `{ "users": [ ... ] }`.

Comment: @NewUser You just put the JSON code directly inside a `<script>` element, and then define a `type="text/template"` on that SCRIPT to ensure that it doesn't execute as JavaScript.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - when I remove the `[]` AJAX is not successful and come back with with `SyntaxError: invalid label`, but code is 200

Comment: @NewUser That's because your file extension is `.js`, so jQuery tries to execute it as JavaScript code. Change the extension to `.json`.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - how do you reference it without `var name`?

Comment: @NewUser Check out [this site](http://handlebarsjs.com/) (the second code block). It shows how to put a template inside a SCRIPT element.

Comment: @NewUser You set an ID: `<script id="myTemplate">`, and then `var template = $('#myTemplate').text();`.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - once changes js -> json all works! Many thanks!

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - is H`andlebars` same as `Mustache`?

Comment: @NewUser Handlebars builds on Mustache, I think. It adds some features, but the basic syntax is the same.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - thanks for help. I will look into the Handlebars as well. thansk!